# Is there a way to use javascript to change the css of multiple html files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using this code, it only affects the file (my settings.html file) where i change the value of the background color:

```
    function background() {
    `var x = document.getElementById('color').value;
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
    }
```

color is the id of the input.

But how can i affect multiple html files with this?

Comment: you can use cookies to store the changed color and load it on every page. or use server side cookie to store user's choice in database. or use server side session to store the color on-change and use it on-load of every page.

Comment: in addition to the cookies method proposed above, you can also have a look at localstorage: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp. It would be similar to the suggestion proposed by Nawed Khan, you can store the value of the color in the localstorage and use it on-load of all the other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you navigate to another page, your HTML and JS script **will be refreshed**, and therefore you will lose your changes.

A possible solution is to use a `cookie` or the browser's `localStorage` in order to save the value of the desired color. Then, it can be reused when navigating pages.

Example of setting a cookie using JS:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Example for localStorage:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: But do you know how to use the cookies so it remembers the value (of the background color) on the other html pages? W3schools doesn't explain it really well.

Comment: Cookies do last until the browser is closed (by default), or until a certain expiration date that you can set. Therefore, just set the cookie in one page, and you should be able to read/edit it on other pages of your website.

Answer (score -1):

You can import the JavaScript file into multiple HTML files:

```
<script src="filename.js">
```

Then run the function in said HTML Files.
Also make sure there is one "color" Id in each HTML File.

Comment: I did, but when I change it and navigate to the other pages, for example, I go from index to settings.html. Then change the value of the background color. And go back to index.html the background color is the default one instead of the color I gave.